# Can not create Pipe in Angular 2 with ES5

Tags: angular

I have a very simple pipe, which follows the commands from https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet:

```
app.DisplayKeystrokePipe = ng.core
    .Pipe({
        name: "displayKeystroke"
    })
    .Class({
        transform: function() {

        }
    });
```

Unfortunately I get the error: `Error: Only Function or Array is supported in Class definition for key 'constructor' is 'undefined'`

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the constructor in your `Class({})`

```js
app.DisplayKeystrokePipe = ng.core
    .Pipe({
        name: "displayKeystroke"
    })
    .Class({
        constructor : function() {}, // <<< ---
        transform: function() {

        }
    });
```

You can read at [decorators.ts](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/src/core/util/decorators.ts#L14-L23) that the constructor is required.

Comment: Well, I removed the constructor because it is giving me a different error: `EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on constructor`. Since they don't have a constructor on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html I'm assuming TypeScript just automatically adds a constructor?

Comment: @Typhox yes, but that's typescript. Typescript does all that magic for us. If you have an issue with that Directive error you should have started with that.

Comment: @Typhox Yes, you should ask a new question. if this answer answers your initial question you may accept it.